# What would be the best way to make a website that lets a user fill a form and receive data (such as real estate listings)?

Tags: search, web-search

I want to make a website that will allow the user to input the zipcode in which they are looking for houses and that will notify me of what their search criteria is (such as homes for $250K in the ##### zip code). What would be the best way to start this project?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a form which would ask for the user to fill in their details and when they submit you receive an email with their details.

You can look into simple bootstrap form and use PHP to implement it

Have a look at this example

[Simple Form Example](http://www.infotuts.com/bootstrap-3-contact-form/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a form that gives price range option. 
-$50,000-$100,000
-$100,000-$150,000
-$150,000-$200,000
-$200,000-$250,000
-$250,000-$300,000
-$300,000+

Then create an input field with validation applied that checks for a certain amount of characters and that the input is integers to help with span.

Finally a submit button that you can set up to email you the results or if you are working with a database you can send it there and monitor it or create a page that displays the requests you get. The email structure would be pretty easy to set up.

This can all be done with simple php and html.